# Singleton with Android

Tags: java, android, singleton

I'm having a bit of trouble using the singleton pattern correctly in my android studio project. I created a textView in my mainActivity class in which I want to set the text of that textView the string value of the variable "a" in the GrouseSingleton class. However, the textView always displays as "hello" (the way it was initialized) and not the actual string it should be (it should be "mainly cloudy skies", parsed from the website). I'm assuming that I'm not set the variable "a" correctly in the singleton class. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

SINGLETON CLASS CODE:

```
public class GrouseSingleton extends AppCompatActivity {

private static GrouseSingleton instance = null;
public Document grouseWeather;
public String a = "hello";

private GrouseSingleton() throws IOException {
    startThread();
}

public static GrouseSingleton getInstance() throws IOException {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new GrouseSingleton();
    }
    return instance;

    }

    public void startThread() throws IOException {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    grouseWeather = Jsoup.connect("https://www.grousemountain.com/current_conditions#weather").get();
                    runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            a = grouseWeather.select("h3.metric").first().text();
                            setA(a);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }

    public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
    }
```

}

MAIN ACITVITY CODE:

```
     try {
         grouseSingleton = GrouseSingleton.getInstance();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     TextView tv45 = findViewById(R.id.textView45);
     tv45.setText(grouseSingleton.a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your singleton is fine. The issue is that you create the instance of class `GrouseSingleton`  and then right after that you get the value of `a` which is the default value "hello" . So you need to use an `interface` like below to inform your `activity` when the value of `a` is fetched from server:

```
public interface ResultListener {
    void onResultFetched(int textViewId, String txt);
}
```

In your Activity:

```
try {
     grouseSingleton = GrouseSingleton.getInstance(new ResultListener () {
        @Override
        public void onResultFetched(int textViewId, String txt) {
            TextView tv45 = findViewById(id);
            tv45.setText(txt);
        });
     grouseSingleton.startThread();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

set the listener in your `GrouseSingleton` class:

```
private static ResultListener listener;
public static GrouseSingleton getInstance(ResultListener listener) throws IOException {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new GrouseSingleton();
        GrouseSingleton.listener = listener;
    }
    return instance;
}


public void startThread() throws IOException {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                grouseWeather = Jsoup.connect("https://www.grousemountain.com/current_conditions#weather").get();
                runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        a = grouseWeather.select("h3.metric").first().text();  
                        listener.onResultFetched(txtViewId, a);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the reply. I tried it out but got stuck here where it wants me to make the getInstance method non-static. If I make it non-static, then when I call getInstance in the main activity, it says that the method cannot be referenced from a static context. Is there away around this?

Comment: You are totally right. I edited the answer. Just change `private ResultListener listener` to `private static ResultListener listener` and let me know the result.

Comment: I think it worked after I changed it to " GrouseSingleton.listener = listener;", this.listener = listener still wouldn't work for some reason. But thanks so much it works perfectly!

Comment: By the way, do you know if there's a more efficient way of setting the variable values in the singleton class other than the setA(a) method I'm using? I'm going to be updating quite a few textViews so it would be great if I didn't have to create a method for each textView haha

Comment: I edited the answer to fit your condition. You don't need to use `setA()`. Instead directly pass the result value to your `activity`. Supposing you know which `TextView` is going to be updated, then you also can pass its `id` to `activity` for ease of use. @Kevin

Comment: Got it thanks! Sorry to bother you once more, but when I use another class to access the singleton, the textViews don't seem to be updated when the second class calls the singleton (when an instance is already made). Is there a way to fix this? Sorry for all the questions..

Comment: It is because the `listener` is set only once. To solve this you have to set the `listener` even when the `instance` is not `null`. This will solve your problem but it is not a good practice anyways @Kevin

Answer (score 0):

All code is fine. But the problem is before load data `textview` set default value `hello`. Afterload data it's cannot update the value. To simply achieve this just sent your `textView` as a parameter when calling your singleton. like:

SingletonClass:

```
public class GrouseSingleton extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static GrouseSingleton instance = null;
    public Document grouseWeather;
    public String a = "hello";
    TextView textView;

    private GrouseSingleton(TextView textView) throws IOException {
        this.textView = textView;
        startThread();
    }

    public static GrouseSingleton getInstance(TextView textView) throws IOException {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new GrouseSingleton(textView);
        }
        return instance;

    }

    public void startThread() throws IOException {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    grouseWeather = Jsoup.connect("https://www.grousemountain.com/current_conditions#weather").get();
                    runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            a = grouseWeather.select("h3.metric").first().text();
                            textView.setText(a);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

And from MAinActivity:

```
TextView tv45 = findViewById(R.id.textView45);
try {
   grouseSingleton = GrouseSingleton.getInstance(tv45);
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
tv45.setText(grouseSingleton.a);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Is there a way of doing this if I'm going to be updating around 100 textViews since putting over 100 fields in the constructor wouldn't really work well?